# how to initialize all values of an integer array to 0 in c++?

Tags: c++

In character array we can write

`char ZEROARRAY[1024] = {0};`

but how do we initialize zero value in integer array.

Comment: `char` is _an integer type_ in C++. The syntax is the same for all integer types as well (short, long, wchar_t, ...).

Answer (score 2):

It's similar:

```
int ZEROARRAY[1024] = {0};
```

or even simpler:

```
int ZEROARRAY[1024] = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly same way

```
int zeroarray[1024] = {0};
```